# AWS S3 with Spring Boot error "profile file cannot be null"

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have IAM role and client region. How to grant permission to access S3 in my Spring boot app which is not present inside EC2 instance?

```
@Configuration
public class AWSConfiguration {

    String clientRegion = "...";
    String roleARN = "...";

    @Bean
    public AmazonS3 amazonS3Client() {

        try {
            AWSSecurityTokenService stsClient = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()).withRegion(clientRegion).build();

            AssumeRoleRequest roleRequest = new AssumeRoleRequest().withRoleArn(roleARN);
            AssumeRoleResult roleResponse = stsClient.assumeRole(roleRequest);
            Credentials sessionCredentials = roleResponse.getCredentials();

            BasicAWSCredentials basicAwsCred = new BasicAWSCredentials(sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(), sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey());

            return AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAwsCred)).withRegion(clientRegion).build();

        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: profile file cannot be null
    at com.amazonaws.util.ValidationUtils.assertNotNull(ValidationUtils.java:37) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:142) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:133) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfilesConfigFile.<init>(ProfilesConfigFile.java:100) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider.getCredentials(ProfileCredentialsProvider.java:135) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:833) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:783) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.946.jar:na]
```

I tried to change **ProfileCredentialsProvider** to **DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance()** but it is still giving me same error and also asking me for role session name.

Comment: Is your credentials configured somewhere (Environment Variables, Java System Properties, etc ?)

Comment: No. I am assuming based on roleArn and clientRegion, AWS SDK will fetch credentials and set it in java system properties. I am referring this as reference https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AuthUsingTempSessionTokenJava.html

Comment: you still need to be authentificate first to be able to retrieve session credential

Comment: I am new to AWS. Is there any other way to connect with S3 by only having roleArn and clientRegion?

Comment: No, AWS need to check first if you are allow to assume the role. If you are on promise, you need to use env or system properties, etc... if you run your app in EC2 you can configure the role into the instance profile then call to S3 will use the instance role

Comment: @Harsh Kanakhara are you able to get the solution?

Comment: Yes. I have passed client_id and secret in environment variables for AWS pre-defined keys. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/guide_credentials_environment.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide your credentials using env variables, java system properties, etc. [SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/auth/DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.html) to be able to assume a role. This is not mandatory if your code is running from EC2 instance with Instance Profile correctly configured, the role will be used automatically.

This is a 2 steps process:

- you need to authenticate with an user which is authorized to assume the role
- then you can retrieve session credentials for the role and use them to access S3 with role permissions

To use in EC2, you can find the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html).

EDIT:

A good page to learn about best pratices to access AWS using access keys: [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html)

> For applications, AWS CLI, and Tools for Windows PowerShell commands that run on the instance, you do not have to explicitly get the temporary security credentials—the AWS SDKs, AWS CLI, and Tools for Windows PowerShell automatically get the credentials from the EC2 instance metadata service and use them. To make a call outside of the instance using temporary security credentials (for example, to test IAM policies), you must provide the access key, secret key, and the session token.

Comment: My spring boot app is not running on EC2 instance. Should I still use STS for authentication?

Comment: I don't think this will be so useful. You can have a dedicated user for your app with minimal permissions you need and use access keys. One thing is if you use STS, you will have to manage token renewal and need an authenticated user to do that

Comment: As per my organization IT team they can only provide me IAM role and region name for now. If I want to avoid STS, is there any alternative to connect to AWS based on only IAM role and region passed?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the older V1 Java S3 API. You should consider moving to the Java V2 API for Amazon S3.

Your issue looks like how you are setting your creds. If you are developing a Spring Boot app, you should set credentials using Environment variables. For example:

```
Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
    S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider.create())
            .region(region)
            .build();
```

If you want to deploy this web app to (for example, AWS Elastic Beanstalk), all you need to do is set the environment variables and your Spring Boot application that interact with Amazon S3.

To see how to successfully invoke Amazon S3 from a Spring Boot web app, see this AWS tutorial tutorial. This tutorial discusses how to build a Spring Boot app that can retrieve images from an Amazon S3 bucket (using the S3 Java V2 API) and analyze them using the Amazon Rekognition service. It also discusses how to deploy the web app to Elastic Beanstalk.

[Creating an example AWS photo analyzer application using the AWS SDK for Java](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_photo_analyzer_app)

Comment: Thanks. I will new S3 API. So, it means anyhow I need to set access key and secret id in my environment variables. By only having IAM role and region name will not work. Right? I was assuming based on my IAM role AWS will provide me temporary credentials to access S3.

Comment: Correct - you need to set the IAM role's creds in environment variables for a web app. If you are running code in your desktop, you can set them in the credentials file. As you are new, see the AWS DEV topic -- it will help you.... https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/get-started.html